# How to insert into realm database with specific position and how to retrieve the data with that position in android?

Tags: android, realm

I am using retrofit to parse youtube api json data and used tablayout and viewpager.titles are coming correctly and the data is only coming for the first youtube playlist and the same repeating for the other fragments.saved data to realm like this

```
private void setAdapterVideos(final List<YoutubeVideoDetails> items, final List<YoutubePlayListVideos> videosList) {
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(items);
                                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(videosList);
                            }
                        });
                    }`
```

and retrieved the data like this

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                videosList = realm.where(YoutubePlayListVideos.class).findAll();
                videoDetails = realm.where(YoutubeVideoDetails.class).findAll();
            }
        });
        if (videosList.size() > 0) {
            new LogUtil("aaaaaaaaaaa",posi+": "+videosList.get(0).getSnippet().getTitle());

            VideoAdapter vAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getActivity(), videosList, videoDetails);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(vAdapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I am new to realm database used only SQ Lite and any help would be appreciated...!

Comment: I don't really understand this question, nor is there enough info here for me to get it.

Comment: in tablayout with view pager with dynamic data the fragment has to load data according to the title (works fine without realm ie. direct)and if realm used foe all fragments it loads only first data

Comment: Is the relevant code for this logic in these snippets?

Comment: yes.it has .i trying hard to get it.                                                  
        videosList = realm.where(YoutubePlayListVideos.class).findAll();

Comment: In that case, I don't understand the question at all! :D